# Stripe cashier, ignore customers migration

Tags: laravel

I installed Laravel Cashier, I migrated the tables but when I want to re-migrate after the first one with a fesh --seed it tells me that there is a problem with the customers table of cashier.

I published the vendors but I find myself with the customers & users table, I deleted the customers table but it still keeps it for me, so I ignored the migrations and kept the 2 subscription tables of cashier but it still doesn't work:

```
  Cannot declare class CreateSubscriptionsTable, because the name is already in use

  at database/migrations/2021_07_04_000002_create_subscriptions_table.php:7
```

Cannot declare class CreateSubscriptionsTable, because the name is already in use

I added this in AppServiceProvider :

```
Cashier::ignoreMigrations();
```

Here is my user table, I added the fields of the customers table:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->uuid('id')->primary();

            $table->foreignUuid('rank_id')->constrained('ranks');

            $table->string('stripe_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('pm_type')->nullable();
            $table->string('pm_last_four', 4)->nullable();
            $table->timestamp('trial_ends_at')->nullable();

            $table->string('username');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->integer('profile_visibility')->default(\App\Models\User::PROFILE_PUBLIC);
            $table->integer('status')->default(0);
            $table->timestamp('last_seen_feed')->default(Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString());
            $table->timestamp('last_seen_comments')->default(Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString());

            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

`php artisan migrate:fresh` might be the solution here, try add seeders from different command `php artisan db:seed --class:NameofSeedSeeder`

More under documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations